# Pipe commands with fork and dup2

Tags: c, redirect, process, pipe, file-descriptor

I wrote the following code in order to pipe two commands:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char    *program_1[3] = {"/bin/cat", "/dev/random", NULL};
char    *program_2[2] = {"/bin/ls", NULL};
char    *program_3[2] = {"/usr/bin/sort", NULL};

int main(void)
{
    int fd[2];
    int pid;

    pipe(fd);
    if ((pid = fork()) == 0) //Child process
    {
        dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(fd[0]);
        execve(program_3[0], program_3, NULL);
    }
    else if (pid > 0) //Parent process
    {
        dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        close(fd[1]);
        execve(program_2[0], program_2, NULL);
    }
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Each pair of program_x / program_y where x != y works fine, except this one.
When i pipe sort into ls, ls well prints its output on stdout, but then, sort throw this error: `sort: Input/output error`.

When I type `sort | ls` into bash, it prints ls result as my program, but then waits for input.

Am I doing someting wrong ?

edit: I'm trying to reimplement the shell's behaviour

Comment: `sort | ls` is meaningless, as there's no input to `sort` and `ls` takes no input. Do you mean `ls | sort` instead?

Comment: `ls | sort` works fine in my case, but `sort | ls` (even if it's meaningless) doesn't show same output than bash, and i don't figure out why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution, we were close to:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

char    *cat[3] = {"/bin/cat", "/dev/random", NULL};
char    *ls[2] = {"/bin/ls", NULL};
char    *sort[2] = {"/usr/bin/sort", NULL};

int main(void)
{
    int fd[2];
    pid_t pid;
    pid_t pid2;

    pipe(fd);
    if ((pid = fork()) == 0)
    {
        dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(fd[0]);
        execve(cat[0], cat, NULL);
    }
    else if (pid > 0)
    {
        if ( (pid2 = fork()) == 0)
        {
            dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
            close(fd[1]);
            execve(ls[0], ls, NULL);
        }
        waitpid(pid2, 0, 0);
        close(fd[0]);
    }
    waitpid(pid, 0, 0);
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

We need to close the read end of the pipe once the last process ends, this way, if the first process tries to write on the pipe, an error will be throwed and the process will exit, else if it only reads from stdin as `sort`, it will keep reading as stdin is still open

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when `ls` finishes, the parent process will exit which will close the read-end of the pipe, which will lead to an error being propagated to the write-end of the pipe which is detected by `sort` and it write the error message.

That it doesn't happen in the shell is because shells handle pipes differently than your simple example program, and it keeps the right-hand side of the pipe open and running (possibly in the background) until you pass `EOF` (<kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd>) to the `sort` program.

Comment: So when does bash closes those file descriptors?
And when does a bash command "end"?

Answer (score 0):

Your program isn't quite equivalent to what a shell typically does.

You're replacing the parent with `ls`; whereas shell would create who child processes and connect them and wait for them to finish.

It's more like:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

char    *program_2[2] = {"/bin/ls", NULL};
char    *program_3[2] = {"/usr/bin/sort", NULL};

int main(void)
{
    int fd[2];
    pid_t pid;
    pid_t pid2;

    pipe(fd);
    if ((pid = fork()) == 0) //Child process
    {
        dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(fd[0]);
        execve(program_3[0], program_3, NULL);
    }
    else if (pid > 0) //Parent process
    {
        if ( (pid2 = fork()) == 0) {
            dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
            close(fd[1]);
            execve(program_2[0], program_2, NULL);
        }
    }

    waitpid(pid, 0, 0);
    waitpid(pid2, 0, 0);
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: With your exemple, `sort | ls`works fine but `cat /dev/random | ls` will wait for cat to finish, while bash doesn't. Buf if I just remove the first waitpid call, will cat run as long as my program is running ? More if I remove this waitpid call, same issue come bask (sort error). Do you know how does bash handle it ?

Comment: @Bccyv Instead of waiting for one after other you could wait for in a loop with: `while(waitpid(-1, 0, WNOHANG)) != -1);` for all. I am not sure exactly how bash handles it. But this makes sense as you would reap a child as soon as possible.

Comment: Samething with `while(waitpid(-1, 0, WNOHANG)) != -1);`

Comment: @Bccyv Did you remove the `waitpid` calls?

Comment: I removed the waitpid calls, `sort | ls` waits as bash, but `cat /dev/random | ls` still waits either

Comment: Indeed, It does. I'll check bash source code when I get time.

Comment: I checked Bash code source this morning but it's way too hard for me, I'm pretty new to C. I'll continue to try to figure out how does it works by testing