# Trouble understanding bash piping behaviour

Tags: linux, bash, shell, pipe

I'm a bit confused on how does bash performs pipe redirections.

First on piping behaviour:

`cat /dev/random | ls` doesn't waits cat and ends as soon as ls result is printed, however
`cat /dev/random | grep foo` waits for cat before executing grep.
It make sense because ls doesn't need cat result to work as grep do, but I don't understand how it can work, does bash waits processes with waitpid calls on some processes? Does it waits for `EOF` on write end of the pipe's right side, and on read end on the pipe's left side?

More, I'm not sure about which commands are forked or not and where it's done:

I guess built-in commands are exectuted in the main process as most of them are used to modify some shell settings. On the other hand (I guess), binary are always executed in a subprocess, with `fork`, am I right?
If I am, it means piping redierction doesn't call `fork` itself as it don't know if the commands to execute are built-ins or not.

Bash source code is way too far from my skills, I don't understand it, can someone explain me how it behaves?

I tried to reimplement its behaviour (without success), [I asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61186772/pipe-commands-with-fork-and-dup2/61187380#61187380), with some code if you want to check.

Comment: Because some utility/program does not accept input from `stdin`, like `ls` as opposed to, say  `grep`

Comment: But if you try to `sort | ls`, even if ls doesn't accept input, `sort` will continue to wait for input after ls prints its result, more, I think bash doesn't know which program takes or not input, so how can it handle every case as it does?

Comment: `bash` does not interfere on how the processes handle their inputs. `bash` only prepares the different channels (stdout of first process to stdin of second process) and start the processes. Then waits for them to finish.

Comment: In the in `cat /dev/random | ls`, bash starts both processes. `ls` does not even look at `stdin`, it just do its job and finish. Whan `ls` finish, `cat` see that  the output strem has been closed and also finish ()with a "cannot write error" that can be shown to the user or not).

Comment: in the `cat /dev/random | grep foo`, bash starts both processes. `grep` reads its input, which comes form `cat` and both perform its jobs simultaneously. As `/dev/random` is infinite, they will run until you stop them, outputting each `foo` that is found in `/dev/random`.

Comment: In the `sort | ls`, bash starts both processes. The difference with the previous `cat ... | ls` invocation is that `cat` inmediately opens its `stdout` for writing its input, but `sort` does not open its `stdout` until there's something to output. As you don't give `sort` any file to sort, it reads from `stdin` and is blocked for input. Meanwhile, `ls` does its work and finish. `sort` is waiting for your input. As soon as you give your input to sort and close `sort`'s `stdin`, it will try to open its stdout and will discover that there's nobody reading behind.

Comment: But, as you can see, all of this stream mangling is done by the different processes started by `bash`, not by `bash` itself.

Comment: So if I understood, bash first creates the pipe tube, redirects I/O, then executes both processes (that can be eecuted into subprocesses or not) and waits for both?
Then, pipe sides are closed at the end of each process (after a potential wait call?)